# Is there a better way to iterate over multiple lists and append results?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, coding-efficiency

I'm calculating the number of occurrences of certain words (within "dictionaries") in a given file.

While my code below works perfectly fine, it's painful to the eyes and almost certainly is an embarrassment to the Zen of Python.

I'd really appreciate any tips on how I can make the "goliath loop" cleaner and more efficient.

Each score must have its own unique counter, and each dictionary must have its own unique name. That made me rule out looping over some sort of range. 
**Full background**
I have about 140,000 text tiles, and 9 "dictionaries", each with a varying number of total words. For each file, I clean the text and then count the number of words within a given text file which matches a word in each of the 9 dictionaries.

```
for file in all_files:
    # Extract firm and year identifiers from file names
    cik_identifier = file[70:-4].split('_')[0]
    financial_year = file[70:-4].split('_')[1]
    filing_year = file[70:-4].split('_')[2]
    filing_type = '10K'

    # Conduct final cleaning of text file
    with open(file) as my_file:
        text = my_file.read()
        words = text.split()
        lower_case_words = [word.lower() for word in words]
        alphabetic_only = [word for word in lower_case_words if word.isalpha()]
        cleaned_words = \
            [word for word in alphabetic_only if word not in stop_words]

    # Log length of text doc pre and post clean
    num_words_pre_clean = len(lower_case_words)
    num_words_post_clean = len(cleaned_words)

    # Calculate Sentiment Scores
    first_sentiment_score = 0
    second_sentiment_score = 0
    third_sentiment_score = 0
    fourth_sentiment_score = 0
    fifth_sentiment_score = 0
    sixth_sentiment_score = 0
    seventh_sentiment_score = 0
    eighth_sentiment_score = 0
    ninth_sentiment_score = 0

    # Goliath loop begins
    for word in cleaned_words:
        for first_sentiment_word, second_sentiment_word, third_sentiment_word, \
            fourth_sentiment_word, fifth_sentiment_word, sixth_sentiment_word, \
            seventh_sentiment_word, eighth_sentiment_word, ninth_sentiment_word in itertools.zip_longest(dict_first, dict_second,
                                                   dict_third, dict_fourth,
                                                   dict_fifth, dict_sixth,
                                                   dict_seventh, dict_eighth, dict_ninth):
                if first_sentiment_word == word:
                    first_sentiment_score += 1
                elif second_sentiment_word == word:
                    second_sentiment_score += 1
                elif third_sentiment_word == word:
                    third_sentiment_score += 1
                elif fourth_sentiment_word == word:
                    fourth_sentiment_score += 1
                elif fifth_sentiment_word == word:
                    fifth_sentiment_score += 1
                elif sixth_sentiment_word == word:
                    sixth_sentiment_score += 1
                elif seventh_sentiment_word == word:
                    seventh_sentiment_score += 1
                elif eighth_sentiment_word == word:
                    eighth_sentiment_score += 1
                elif ninth_sentiment_word == word:
                    ninth_sentiment_score += 1


    # Append identifier, num words, and trust score to df
    sentiment_analysis_data = {'cik' : cik_identifier,
                           'financial_year_end' : financial_year,
                           'filing_year_end' : filing_year,
                           'filing_type' : filing_type,
                           'num_words_pre_clean' : num_words_pre_clean,
                           'num_words_post_clean' : num_words_post_cean,
                           'first_sentiment_score' : first_sentiment_score,
                           'second_sentiment_score' : second_sentiment_score,
                           'third_sentiment_score' : third_sentiment_score,
                           'fourth_sentiment_score' : fourth_sentiment_score,
                           'fifth_sentiment_score' : fifth_sentiment_score,
                           'sixth_sentiment_score' : sixth_sentiment_score,
                           'seventh_sentiment_score' : seventh_sentiment_score,
                           'eighth_sentiment_score' : eighth_sentiment_score,
                           'ninth_sentiment_score' : ninth_sentiment_score}

    all_scores.append(sentiment_analysis_data)
```

Comment: Instead of all those 9 variables, why not **a** list with 9 elements?

Comment: As in scores = [first_sentiment_score, second_sentiment_score, ... , ningth_sentiment_score]
?

Comment: NameError: name 'cleaned_words' is not defined. So please read this link before asking questions [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry @MediaEU; added the preceding code now!

Answer (score 1):

A list of counters is still a set of unique counters.

```
sentiment_scores = [0] * 9
```

And a list of dicts is still a set of unique dicts.

```
dicts = [dict_one, dict_two, ...]  # etc
```

Now you can write your loop in a  way less likely to blind you.

```
# Goliath loop begins
for word in cleaned_words:
    for sentiment_words in itertools.zip_longest(*dicts):
        for i, sentiment_word in enumerate(sentinment_words):
            if sentiment_word == word:
                sentiment_score[i] += 1


# Append identifier, num words, and trust score to df
sentiment_analysis_data = {'cik' : cik_identifier,
                   'financial_year_end' : financial_year,
                   'filing_year_end' : filing_year,
                   'filing_type' : filing_type,
                   'num_words_pre_clean' : num_words_pre_clean,
                   'num_words_post_clean' : num_words_post_cean,
                   'first_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[0],
                   'second_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[1],
                   'third_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[2],
                   'fourth_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[3],
                   'fifth_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[4],
                   'sixth_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[5],
                   'seventh_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[6],
                   'eighth_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[7],
                   'ninth_sentiment_score' : sentiment_score[8]}
```

Ideally, `sentimenat_analysis_data` could take a single key `'sentiment_scores'` that maps to the list of scores, but it's not clear from the question where, if any where, you can make that change.

Comment: Wow, that looks a hell of a lot cleaner and better than mine! Thanks very much @chepner!

Just wondering if `sentiment_scores = [0] * 9` will work within the loop?

Lemme just update the main question with the full loop so it's clearer

Comment: Just updated it with the full loop now; didn't include the previous bits earlier as I didn't want to overcomplicate it.

Comment: Yes, just replace the block of `*_sentiment_score` assignments with that line.

Comment: Just ran it on a small sample and it works like a charm - thanks ever so much! How would I go about cleaning the last dictionary (`sentiment_analysis_data`)? Especially because the list of scores `sentiment_scores = [0- * 9]` doesn't have any info on the names of the dictionaries?

Comment: Would this work out?
`dict_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
sentiment_analysis_data {'cik' : cik_identifier,
                   'financial_year_end' : financial_year,
                   'filing_year_end' : filing_year,
                   'filing_type' : filing_type,
                   'sentiment_scores' : dict(zip(dict_names, sentiment_scores))
}`